# Error with linking components through a navbar using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to link some components through a navbar using `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",`
The components do get displayed on reloading the page but they don't on clicking on the links in navbar. On Clicking on the links I these get errors .

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /about
    at oe.error (jquery.min.js:2:12961)
    at oe.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2:18943)
    at oe.select (jquery.min.js:2:21833)
    at Function.oe [as find] (jquery.min.js:2:6808)
    at w.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2:24400)
    at new w.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2:24889)
    at w (jquery.min.js:2:896)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (custom.js:22:24)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2:41772)
    at y.handle (jquery.min.js:2:39791)
```

Here's some of the code used .

**index.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
...
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>
);
```

**App.js**

```
import {Routes , Route} from 'react-router-dom'
...
function App() {
  return (
      <>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route  path="/" element = {<Hero />}></Route>
          <Route  path="/about" element = {<About />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </>
  );
}
```

**Navbar.js**

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
...

             <ul className="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a href="#home" className="nav-link smoothScroll">Home</a>
                        </li>

                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to="/about" className="nav-link smoothScroll">About Us</Link>
                        </li>
             <ul>
```

One more thing is there any specific rule like where I can put the Links , Routes and BrowserRouter ?

Comment: Are you using jQuery with the navbar links?

Comment: Code seems fine to me. The error is pointing to something jquery related though. What are you using jquery for? Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: The template I used does contain jQuery . One place where I found it was : 
`$('.navbar a, .hero-text a').on('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 49
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
      });`

Comment: It's generally considered anti-pattern to mix Jquery with React as they have pretty orthogonal approaches to UI management. Try removing the jquery stuff to see if the error clears up.